# How to insert and print list in struct

Tags: c++, struct, doubly-linked-list

I have implementation Double Link List used STL list and i have problem when i access and push_back value list in struct. Here is my struct :

```
typedef struct tanaman{
  string nama;
  list<double> tinggi;
} plant;
```

And I try use the class name Oryza, and here is code :

```
class Oryza{
    list<plant> pt;
public:
    int isEmpty(){ pt.empty();}
    void push_back(plant val) { pt.push_back(val);}
    void print();
};
```

And my question is, how i insert to list tinggi in struct.

```
int main(){
    Oryza jagung;
    int n,m;
    float t;
    string nama;
    plant data;

    cin >> n;
    while(n--){
        cin >> nama >> m;
        data.nama=nama;
        while(m--){
            cin >> t;
            ???????
        }
        jagung.push_back(data);
    }

    jagung.print();
    return 0;
}
```

and example input :

> 2
>  F123 5 56.2 32.4 14.2 43.7 10.5
>  B651 2 89.9 87.2

Comment: I have a more fundamental question: What value do you think `Oryza::isEmpty()` is `return`-ing? (hint intentional)

Comment: function Oryza::isEmpty() return value is int, and I repair, `int Oryza::isEmpty() { return dt.Empty(); }`. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while should look as:

```
while(n--){
    cin >> nama >> m;
    data.nama = nama;
    while(m--){
        cin >> t;
        data.tinggi.push_back(t);   // Change 1
    }
    jagung.push_back(data);
    data.tinggi.clear();  // Change 2
}
```

You must push object into the `data` and make sure to clear the `tinggi` before next iteration to avoid data repetition.

It would be good to change the type of `t` from `float` to `double`.

Comment: okey thank you very much, maybe I will change data type `t` to `double` because `tinggi` in struct is data type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data.tinggi.push_back(t);
```

Comment: Please provide more details on why this answer is helpful.